# The word for "Those who are notified"

Tags: grammar, single-word-requests

In general usage (and hopefully correct usage) a "notifier" is someone who notifies.

What is the word for the person who is notified?

For example: "Instruct each [X] to respond to the notification within 3 days."

Comment: Using "notification recipient" or simply "recipient" gets you close.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While I expect that you're looking for something like *notifiee*, I'm not aware of any such word that would have that exact meaning.  That being said, there are several good options that could work:

In the general case, (though these may overuse the *notify* root for your taste):

> Instruct each of the notified to respond...
>
> Instruct each notified individual to respond...

If the notification is a written message that they received.

> Instruct each recipient to respond...

If the notification is some sort of pop-up in a program

> Instruct each user to respond...

Comment: +1 - you could also use a noun that is specific to the situation, e.g. 'instruct each resident', 'instruct each student', etc., depending on who the people are. But if you want something more generic I don't think you'll get anything better than Dusty's suggestions.

Comment: I'd just go with the generic 'recipient'

Answer (score 5):

If those that are notified had to subscribe (e.g. to a mailing list) to receive the notifications, then you can call them *subscribers*.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/notifyee):

> **Notifyee** (plural *notifyees*)
>
> *(rare, nonstandard)* a person or organization that is being notified

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!  Can you add the source where you found this definition?  (Quoted material without a reference is likely to be deleted; see our [referencing](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) help page for details.)

Comment: Got it from Wiktionary

Comment: _Notifyee_ looks very odd. The formation itself is both regular, transparent and obvious, and I would have no qualms using it, but I would expect it to be written _notifiee_ (by analogy with _notifier_).

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old and you've already accepted another answer, but for the sake of those like me who come after, the word you were looking for is *notificant*.

Comment: This word is not in any dictionary I have access to here (on my phone, so no OED, etc.), and it sounds like it should mean the person notifying someone, not the person notified. Moreover, all Google hits refer to an app called Notificant. In other words: does this word even exist?

Comment: It's not at Dictionary.com: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Notificant?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic. @siemova I like the word, but it's certainly not in general usage.

Comment: It's not in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=notificant&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch).  The OED asks if "modificand" is meant, which of course is not.